# How to re-use existing browser session in selenium with robot frame work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, session, browser, robotframework

I am currently working on a test automation project using Robot Framework and Selenium with python for our application and I've encountered a few challenges and would greatly appreciate your guidance and expertise in resolving them.
I'm struggling with managing browser cookies across test cases.
I need to save my credentials in a variable and re use it in another test case files.
All I want to do is,

1. Run a login test case that logs into an application and stores cookies.
2. Run other test cases (e.g., application's tabs) without needing to log in again by using the stored cookies.
   Can someone help me to do this with code examples? Thank you.

ABC_Test_Automation/
├── ABC_ACM_TC
│   ├── ABC_Login.robot
│   ├── Setting. Robot
│   ├── TestSuite.robot
│
└── Resources
└── Resources. Robot

- This is my folder and file structure.
- ABC_Login.robot - include application login details and save it as a cookie.
- Setting. Robot - this is another test case in my application , I need to open this without re entering username and password again by using cookies of login testcase.
- TestSuite.robot - I use this to store my all test cases and run those in sequential manner.

Comment: I've not tried myself, but see two options to investigate:   **1. ** Get all the cookies before closing browser by [Get Cookies](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Cookies) and store them in a suite or global scope variable. And then after starting a new test and new browser add all the cookies back by [Add Cookie](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Add%20Cookie)

Comment: **2.** The second one is to use one browser instance for all test suites. E.g. not to close the browser after each test. Open before the first test and close after the very last one.  E.g. Open it in the top Suite Setup and close in the top Suite Teardown.